# iOS 4.3 causes black screen (4.0-4.2 was fine) - MPMoviePlayerController at fault?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios4

I've made a game that uses cocos2d to display graphics, and uses a lot of MPMoviePlayerController to display cutscenes.

The problem is - the game stopped working on iOS 4.3. It was fine up until iOS 4.2, but on iOS 4.3 the movies play OK, the gameplay also happens, but the screen is all black when not playing the movies.

I have a hard time tracking the problem. Suggestions?

**Edit:** I narrowed the thing down to MPMoviePlayerController - if I disable it, everything is fine. I guess something changed in 4.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerController's view is clear in 4.0-4.2, and black in 4.3 by default, what helped was:

```
MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = ...
moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I just tried it on mine, and it works great. What isn't working about that for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = ...
[moviePlayer.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
// or set need color
```

read more in "MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference"